# Is it safe to use the python word "type" in my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reserved-words

Can I use the word `type` in my own code or is it reserved? My function header:

```
def get(
    self,
    region='Delhi',
    city='Delhi',
    category='Apartments',
    type='For sale',
    limit=60,
    PAGESIZE=5,
    year=2012,
    month=1,
    day=1,
    next_page=None,
    threetapspage=0,
):
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using `type` as a keyword argument to a function will mask the [built-in function "type"](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) within the scope of the function. So while doing so does not raise a `SyntaxError`, it is not considered good practice, and I would avoid doing so.

Comment: However, inside the function scope I don't see a big issue with it. Same for `id` which is even more common.

Comment: I avoid using naming variables `id` for just this reason. Isn't this a bad idea, since other developers could try to use the builtin and experience strange behavior? If you could provide a link to a framework/library that does this I'd be willing to reconsider.

Comment: IMHO it really depends on the context and the function.

Comment: I was just on the receiving end of some code that defined ```list``` as a variable. It was a bit of a sprawling function so it wasn't immediately obvious that the ```list()``` builtin was being masked when I tried to use it.

Comment: What about upper case `Type`?

Answer (score 16):

Neither. It's not a reserved word (a list of which can be found at http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords ), but it's generally a bad idea to shadow any builtin.

Comment: Incidentally, `import keyword; print keyword.kwlist` will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

While others have pointed out that it's bad form to shadow python built-ins, this is only the case when either name a function or function parameter as `type`, however -

It should be noted that the python built-in `type` is not shadowed in any way if you were to name a class attribute as `type`.

Even when referencing your class attribute, it would always be prefixed by the class instance `self` or a custom instance variable - and the python built-in would not be hindered.

For example:

## Okay:

```
>>> class SomeClass():
...     type = 'foobar'
...
...     def someFunction(self):
...         return self.type
```

## Not Okay:

```
>>> def type(): # Overrides python built-in in global scope
...     pass
...
>>> def foobar(type):
...     return type # Overrides python built-in within func
```

Comment: If you use typing hints, the first is not okay. Consider this:
class SomeClass:
    type: type | None = None

Answer (score 4):

That is more than a decade old question and to be on the safe side, I would recommend using `kind` instead of `type` as argument.

For a long time I was considering building a rename recommendation for all reserved or builins, but seeing your question made me finally do it.

Please check [python-keyword-aliases.md](https://github.com/pycontribs/meta/blob/master/doc/python-keyword-aliases.md) and feel free to propose new entries to that list.

Answer (score 0):

`type` should absolutely be consider a reserved word. While it can be tempting to use this word for database fields, consider that the fact that `type()` is one of the most important debugging/ testing functions because it tells you the `class` of an object.

```
$ python

>>> x = 5
>>> s = "rockets"
>>> y = [1,2,3] 

>>> print(type(x)) 
class 'int'

>>> print(type(s))
class 'str'

>>> print(type(y)) 
class 'list'
```

An atlas would be classified a type of book, but consider using the word "category" instead.

Comment: Even though it is true that we have a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type), I cannot find `type` among the reserved words in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). Am I missing something?
Anyway I will follow your advice and use another word.

Answer (score 0):

A definitive con with shadowing builtin variables like `type` and `id`: if you happen to copy/paste your code that overshadows `id` for example, and then you replace all the instances of your variable with something else, but *forget to rename one instance* so you still have dangling `id` used, the code will still be syntactically valid and linters may very well not even find the error, but you'll get really really weird results when you run the code, because `id` won't be a string or number as you expected.  It'll be the builtin function `id`!

This tripped me up badly a few times.