# Is using "type" as an attribute name a bad practice?

Tags: python, django

I have the following django model:

```
class SomeProfile(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Is using "type" as an attribute name considered a bad practice?

Here the attribute is not shadowing "type", so it's not the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568087/is-it-safe-to-use-the-python-word-type-in-my-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice to use a built-in function name as an attribute or method identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109333/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-built-in-function-name-as-an-attribute-or-method-ide)

Comment: why not just use `_type`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham because leading underscore is used for private class-level or module-level member names (according to PEP-0008). To resolve reserved names clashed, using of _trailing_ underscore is recommended.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy though a trailing underscore looks so ugly

Comment: @Alvaro not uglier than code which violates PEP-0008.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy agreed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. It's not a member of [python's reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html).

However, naming a method `type()` would probably be confusing...

Comment: Even though it works I wouldn't say there's nothing wrong with it. It's potentially confusing to the reader at a minimum.

Comment: How is it more confusing than the way Django uses `id`? `id()` is also a builtin...

Comment: Yeah I don't think it confuses anyone since there is no chance of accessing it without naming the class or an instance (eg. SomeProfile.type or instance.type)

Comment: Methods are just attributes of objects which contain functions. You contradict yourself. Don't use builtin names, once you'll run into a situation when you'll need to name a regular variable as attribute of your object.

Answer (score 6):

General rule is: don't use names that are taken (e.g. `type`, `file`, `int`, etc.) regardless of whether they're in a "reserved" keywords list or not (since python allows it, it's not really "reserved"). This is mainly important to avoid getting into trouble when you actually need to use the real object (without noticing that you overrode it locally).

If you really want to use one of those names, just append `_` at the end (e.g. `type_`).

In your case, since you're specifying `type` as a class attribute, it should be considered safe since it can only be accessed through its class (`self.type` or `SomeProfile.type`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - its bad practice. `type` is very general word from keyword perspective though not a reserved keyword. Even though its not giving any problems currently in your application but it might give in future as it could have been used in some already existing libraries or python extensions.

Example: type being used as a function to get `TypeCast` information of variable

```
name = "John"
age = 12

print type(name)
## Above line will return "<type 'str'>"

print type(age)
## Above line will return "<type 'int'>"
```

Usage of `type` being used as an `attribute` is a bad practice.

Comment: those are functions, not attributes

Comment: Ofcourse - its function. But naming your properties as `type` will surely create confusion. When we already know there is a function named `type` then I recommend not use it as a property name. This can be considered as a best practice.

Comment: Question was about - whether that will be a bad practice or not. As a developer you can always name the property as `type` (wherein Python wont stop you) but when we think about the `USABILITY` + `MAINTAINABILITY` + `READABILITY` its surely a bad practice. Most importantly if something is not going bring any significance to coding practice then why to do that. Instead of `type` one can always use something `category_type` || `entity_type` which would more meaningful as well.