# Storing values in a CSV file into a list in python

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, pandas

I'd like to create a list that stores all values of a single column. 
For example let's say my file has a column called 'FirstNames' and for the first 3 rows, the 'names' column has Merry, Pippin, Frodo.

I'd like to create a list that looks like [Merry, Pippin, Frodo]

I tried doing it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(".../TrainingFile.csv")
list = []
names = data['FirstNames']

for i in range(0,2):
    list.append(names[i:i+1])

print(list)
```

However the list does not only store the values in the cells and gives me an output like this:

Name: FirstName, dtype: object, 1 Merry

Name: FirstName, dtype: object, 2 Pippin

Name: FirstName, dtype: object, 3 Frodo

How can I change this? Thanks for the help.

Bonus: instead of range(0,2) how can I define the range so that it goes through the number of rows there are in the file?

Comment: Please fix indentation after `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please never use reserved words like `list`, `type`, `id`... as variables because masking built-in functions.

If later in code use `list` e.g.

```
list = data['FirstNames'].tolist()
#another solution for converting to list
list1 = list(data['SecondNames'])
```

get very  weird errors and debug is very complicated.

So need:

```
L = data['FirstNames'].tolist()
```

Or:

```
L = list(data['FirstNames'])
```

Also can check [Is it safe to use the python word “type” in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10568087/2901002).

Comment: I wrote this code quickly to ask this question but you're right, noted! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Glad can help! After a few hours of debugging I never use this reserved words again ;(

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using reserved variable names.
Instead of using list, use list1 or something else as the variable name.

Few of the reserved variable names in python are: **dict, str, list, int, pass** etc, which we use mistakenly. Try to avoid it.