# Adding/Subtracting values in dictionary via user inputs

Tags: python, function, dictionary, input

```
attributes = {"Health": 0, "Strength": 0, "Dexterity": 0,   
"Intelligence": 0}

points = 40

def add_points(attributes):
    type = input("Which attribute would you like to adjust?: ")
    if type in attributes:
        how_many = int(input("Add how many points?: "))
        if how_many <= points:
            type += how_many
    return type

add_points(attributes)
```

Some context.  The code above is a piece of my character creator program I am building.  I have the entire program written, however I want to use a function rathre than typing a bunch of loops.  Trying to make my code more concise and Pythonic.

I cannot figure out how to take the value of whatever key is chosen by the user and add x amount of points (also chosen by the user) to the value assigned to said key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `attributes[type]+= how_many`.

Comment: P.S: just a side remark, avoid using the `type` keyword as a variable name in python.

Comment: madjaoue, why is that a convention?

Comment: also you can use `dict.fromkeys()` to create your dictionary from names only (and the same 0 value)

Comment: For using `type`, may be you can look into similar discussion in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10568115/5916727

Comment: @harkbot it's a built-in method (a bit more than that actually), you don't want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

To take the value of a key:

```
 prevValue = attributes.get(type)
```

to change the value:

```
attributes[type] = prevValue + how_many
```

Comment: Ok i've got that part figured out now.  I'm confused on why Python is throwing a syntax error when I try to affect the global variable called points with the amount of points selected by the user.  If I use how_many = int(input("Add how many points?: "))
        if how_many <= global points: that throws a syntax error referring specifically to the use of global.  Any ideas?

Comment: On the line after the function declaration, add a line which says `global points`. Then you can simply reference the global variable anywhere within this function by just writing `points`.