# Python shortcut for variable default value to be another variable value if it is None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function declaration:

```
def set_data(obj=None, name='delp', type=None):
```

Is there a python shortcut, where type is equal with 'name' value(default r passed) if is None ?

Comment: Don't use `reserved words`, for your own sake (and probably everyone else working with your code), please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual idiom is:

```
def set_data(obj=None, name='delp', type=None):
    if type is None:
        type = name
```

(But don't actually use `type` as a variable name, it'll mask the built in function as described here: [Is it safe to use the python word "type" in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568087/is-it-safe-to-use-the-python-word-type-in-my-code))

Comment: It could be just `type = type or name`.

Comment: @Sraw note that this will assign the default if the variable is **any** false-y value, not just `None`

Comment: Sraw - that's not identical in behavior. The empty string is not `None` but it is false, just for one example. If you want to be as concise as possible, a conditional expression (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is one alternative.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Correct, but as here type seems to be a string. And there are only two kinds of false values: empty string or `None`. It could be enough. Although I admit it is not enough for many other situations.

Comment: @Sraw an equivalent one liner would be `type = name if type is None else type`