# Creating a new column in pandas based on a list of values inside a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe which contains the locations of places.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'location': ['Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon', 'Edgbaston', 'Wembley'] })
```

Then I have a list of these places and what the main city they are contained in stored in a dictionary

```
dict ={
['Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon', 'Wembley'] : 'London',
['Edgbaston'] : 'Birmingham'
}
```

**Question:** How could I create a new column (say `df1['city']`) which uses this dictionary to populate which city each of the `location` column entries is in. **Note**: If creating a dictionary to do this isnt the ideal way feel free to suggest an alternative.

***Ideal Output***: Would like something as shown below (this should generalise for more entries providing the dictionary is extended if need be).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'location': ['Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon', 'Edgbaston', 'Wembley'], 'city': ['London','London','London','Birmingham','London'] })
```

**Tried**: Using the apply method but seems to give an error

```
df1['city'] = df1['location'].apply(dict)
```

Comment: Is dict correct ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure but I think the error I got was when running the `apply` method.

Comment: Oh sorry! No in this case I forgot to add `wembley` into the `dict`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary is not valid, you can use list for values of dictionary, also not call dictioanry like `dict`, because python code name, builtins:

```
d = { 'London': ['Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon'],
     'Birmingham': ['Edgbaston']}
```

Here is possible flatten values in lists and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if not exist value is returned missing value:

```
d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (d1)
{'Hackney': 'London', 'Mile End': 'London', 'Croydon': 'London', 'Edgbaston': 'Birmingham'}

df1['city'] = df1['location'].map(d1)
print (df1)
   col1   location        city
0     1    Hackney      London
1     2   Mile End      London
2     3    Croydon      London
3     4  Edgbaston  Birmingham
4     5    Wembley         NaN
```

If dictionary format is tuples in keys:

```
d ={('Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon') : 'London', ('Edgbaston', ) : 'Birmingham'}


d1 = {x: v for k, v in d.items() for x in k}
print (d1)
{'Hackney': 'London', 'Mile End': 'London', 'Croydon': 'London', 'Edgbaston': 'Birmingham'}

df1['city'] = df1['location'].map(d1)
print (df1)
   col1   location        city
0     1    Hackney      London
1     2   Mile End      London
2     3    Croydon      London
3     4  Edgbaston  Birmingham
4     5    Wembley         NaN
```

Comment: I think it is "allowed" to call a dictionary as `dict` - but I agree, it is probably not a good idea

Comment: Thanks but could you explain what you mean when you say my "because python code name, bulletins?

Comment: @nishcs - Sure, because `dict` is dictionary `bulletins`. So for new dict is possible use `d = dict()` But if use `dict={'key': 'val'}` then ift is overwritten and possible weird callable errors (really hard catch), so best never do it. Similar like `list` for list.

Comment: @nishcs - It is like `type` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568087/is-it-safe-to-use-the-python-word-type-in-my-code)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a python `dict` with mutable keys - which means you probably need a tuple instead of a list

```
dict ={
('Hackney', 'Mile End', 'Croydon') : 'London',
('Edgbaston', ) : 'Birmingham'
}
```

Once you have this - you can use the `map` function to map a location to a city. If your dict did not have tuples for keys, you could have used it directly, but in this case - you can define a function -

```
def get_city(location):
    for key in dict.keys():
        if location in key:
            return dict[key]

df1['location'].map(get_city)
#0        London
#1        London
#2        London
#3    Birmingham
#4          None
```

Comment: s/mutable/unhashable/