# Django Form - Validator caused TypeError

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, error-handling

I try to make validator for date and time via regex for data coming from Django Form. I can not figure out why I get 'type" is not iterable when I add validator to field toBeReleased.

views.py:

```
def saveGate(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewGateForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            g = Gate()
            g.save()

            gv = GateVersion()
            gv.gateInternalId = g
            gv.version = form.cleaned_data['version']
            gv.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            gv.toBeReleased = form.cleaned_data['toBeReleased']

            ga = GateAtributes()
            ga.gateInternalId = g
            ga.name = form.cleaned_data['nameOfGate']
            ga.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            ga.gateExpression = form.cleaned_data['gateExpression']
            ga.type = form.cleaned_data['type']

            ga.save()
            gv.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('done/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(ValidationError)
else:
    raise Http404("Unexpected HTTP method.")
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.gates, name='gates'),
path('detail/<str:gateInternalId>/', views.gateDetail, name='detail'),
path('new/', views.newGate, name='new'),
path('new/save', views.saveGate, name='save'),
path('edit/', views.editGate, name='edit'),
path('new/done/', views.done, name='done'),
path('new/version/<str:gateInternalId>/', views.newVersion, name="newVersion"),
path('new/version/saveVersion', views.saveVersion, name='saveVersion'),
path('api/gates', views.apiGates)
```

]

models.py

```
class GateAtributes(models.Model):
gateInternalId = models.ForeignKey(Gate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
atributesInternalId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
gateExpression = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=False)

SHORT_TERM = 'ST'
LONG_TERM = 'LT'
GATE_TYPE_ENUM = [
    (SHORT_TERM, 'Short-term'),
    (LONG_TERM, 'Long-term'),
]

type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GATE_TYPE_ENUM, default=SHORT_TERM)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def __iter__(self):
    return [
        self.gateInternalId,
        self.atributesInternalId,
        self.name,
        self.description,
        self.gateExpression,
        self.type
    ]
```

forms.py

```
class NewGateForm(forms.Form):
nameOfGate = forms.CharField(max_length=500,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control less-marged',
                                                           'placeholder': 'Example - Enable new account opening'}))
gateExpression = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control less-marged', 'placeholder': 'feature.fundament.description'}))
description = forms.CharField(max_length=5000, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control less-marged',
                                                                             'placeholder': 'Example - GateAtributes allows user to open another current accoout'}))
state = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=[
    (True, 'Zapnuto'),
    (False, 'Vypnuto')
]))
type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=[
    ('ST', 'Short-term'),
    ('LT', 'Long-term')
]))
version = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control less-marged', 'placeholder': 'Example - V2'}))

now = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)
current_time = now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
toBeReleased = forms.DateTimeField(validators=[
    RegexValidator(regex='\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}',
                   message='Nesprávný formát datumu nebo času.',
                   code='invalid_format_datetime')],
                                   initial=current_time,
                                   input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'],
                                   widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control less-marged',
                                                                     'placeholder': 'Format - 15.12.2023 10:00'}))
```

When I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/gates/new/save I get following message:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/gates/new/save

Django Version: 4.0.6
Python Version: 3.10.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'kbgates.apps.KbgatesConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Osobni\gates\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Osobni\gates\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Osobni\gates\kbgates\views.py", line 76, in saveGate
    return HttpResponse(ValidationError)
  File "C:\Osobni\gates\venv\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 355, in __init__
    self.content = content
  File "C:\Osobni\gates\venv\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 380, in content
    content = b"".join(self.make_bytes(chunk) for chunk in value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /gates/new/save
Exception Value: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I spend 2 days searching and googling but I did not find any solution to fix issue. If I delete validators from form.py - it works or I dont get the error at least.

I will be thankful to any relevant help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution, but it's worth a try - change `type` to a different name (`kind`?) in your model, and elsewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568087/is-it-safe-to-use-the-python-word-type-in-my-code

Comment: well, i will try. I did not realise that "type" could be dangerous keyword.